# Create unknown amount of columns

Tags: css

Lets say I have some list items:

```
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
   <li>Item 6</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

By default, they are just below each other like this:

- Item 1
- Item 2
- Item 3
- Item 4
- Item 5
- Item 6
- Item 7

But what can I do if I want the ul to have a fixed height, and the items inside should flow in columns like on this picture:

[image]

The width of the different items should be flexible, so if an item gets bigger, the column should also get bigger:

[image]

It seems like a simple use case - but I tried with floats, flex (with wrap), but I cant find any really working solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: seems like flex wrap should work. share the code for what you have tried

Comment: Css columns is what you are looking for.

Comment: With css columns I need to specify an amount. That wont work...

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```css
  ul { 
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 80vh;
  }

  ul li { 
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lavender;
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin: 5px;
    width: fit-content;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>  
  <ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
   <li>Item 4</li>
   <li>Item 5</li>
   <li>Item 6</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
   <li>Item 7</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks - I will try, but that didnt work for me well (for some reason) I will let you know...

Comment: I tried exaclty what you did in this codepen- but the items are behaving differently, even though I copied your code. Can you see here: https://codepen.io/web265p3/pen/KKRdXBg What am I missing? In my example the items are spreading over the screen with much space between them. It should look like in your example.

Comment: The reason is the amount of items - if I put more, it works... almost what I want.

Comment: Try reducing the height of ul or increasing the number of list items.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
The key is "align-content" of flexbox. This property is doing exactly what I want.

Here is my pen: https://codepen.io/web265p3/pen/KKRdXBg

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 1xxxx</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
</ul>

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 200px;
}
ul li {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lavender;
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin: 5px;
    width: fit-content;
}
```